# How can I listen to when the user replies to a permission request?

Tags: android, permissions

So I want to make a method in a class (permission manager) that given a permission (example: `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`), to request that permission and then return true or false if the permission was granted or denied.

I am trying to implement this but I can't get the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method to work anywhere else than in the activity where I am requesting the permission. 
Is there a way to listen to when the user chooses grant or deny? Then I could check the answer and do my thing.

Thanks!

Comment: You can only do it in the same activity which has requested for the runtime permission

Answer (score 2):

> i can't make the onRequestPermissionsResult method to work anywhere else then in the activity where i am requesting the permission

That is the only option.

> Is there a way to listen to when the user choose grant or deny?

Override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in the `Activity` or `Fragment` from which you called `requestPermissions()`.

Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Laur89: you can have the activity or fragment forward the event to other code. There are dozens of libraries for this sort of thing on the Android Arsenal, so you could see how they are implemented, or just use one.